# Java ArrayList - Find Item - Do I need Hash?

Tags: java, arraylist, hashmap

Im learning Java and having a problem with ArrayList. I have read the Java doc and am thinking I maybe need to do the hash thing?

I have an object called catalogue which has an array list of objects created from another class called item. Each item has fields for size, colour, price, product code,  (these are item attributes). I need to include a method in catalogue which accepts a product code and searches through the ArrayList to find the object with matching product code. And then returns that product.
I have a toString method in my item class which lists all of the fields & their values when called. Maybe that is what should be returned when the matching product code is found in array list?

```
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class Catalogue
{

   private ArrayList<Item> catalogue;


    public Catalogue ()
    { 

      catalogue = new ArrayList<Item>();

    }

    public void findItem(int code)
    {
        if(Item.code == prodcode){

        }
        else{
            System.out.println(catalogue.get(item));

        }
    }
```

I looked at Java doc and I read about hash and maybe its better for me to use that rather than iterator? I'm not sure which route to take. My code is half finished
Any help greatly appreciated.
Thankls

Answer (score 3):

What you do can depend on how close together your product codes are.  I'm guessing they aren't sequential, in which case you'd indeed need to use a HashMap.

When you store items in the HashMap, store them keyed by the information you'd like to use when you look them up:

```
Map<Integer, Item> catalog = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
catalog.put(item.code, item);
```

Then when you need to fetch an item based on its product code, use:

`Item item = map.get(code);`

Answer (score 3):

Given the requirements in your question, it doesn't seem like you need to use the hashcode just yet for finding the item in your catalogue. You need to...

1. Traverse the Catalogue
2. For each item in catalogue, see if an item's product code matches and return that

Code may look something like this

```
public Item findItem(int code)
{
    for(Item item: catalogue) {
        if (item.getCode()==code) {
            return item
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could have used hashcodes to speed things up, but for that your catalogue will have to be a HashMap

Comment: Hello thankyou for the reply. I will take your code and see if I can get it to work. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There's a couple of ways you can handle this, but the one that pops to mind is to override the equals and hashcode method for you Item class and use the following:

```
public void findItem(int code) {
    int index = catalogue.indexOf(code);

    if (index == -1) { 
        System.out.println("didn't find the item");
    } else {
        System.out.println(catalogue.get(index));
    }
}
```

Keep in mind you'll have to override your equals and hashCode method to compare two Item objects based on the code member variable only.

If you're doing this quite frequently you might consider creating a HashMap as the lookup time is constant.  You could do that by doing the following:

```
Map<Integer,Item> catalogueLookup = new HashMap<Integer,Item>();
for( Item item : catalogue ) {
    catalogueLookup.put( item.getCode(), item );
}
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Rather than overriding `equals`, it would be better if his class were to implement `Comparable`, create a custom comparator and pass it when needed.

Comment: @Argote: this is only useful when the list is sorted, and we can do a binary-search.

Comment: That's a good point, there's many ways we can tackle this.  I do agree that Comparable would be the cleaner of the two implementations as just having the code member variable determine equality between objects will surely cause issues further down the line.

Answer (score 0):

`ArrayList.get(int)` returns the element at the specified position in this list, `item` is not an `int` (in fact, you're not defining it at all) and in any case you'd only use `get` if you wanted a specific position.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#get%28int%29

Comment: Hello, yes my code is not finished. I cobbled together what I could based on my sparse knowledge of Java so far.
I dont want to return an item at specified index position. I need to return an item based on the matching product code.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using a HashMap instead, that way you will be able to store the items by their (unique, i guess) product code. But then you would also have to override hashCode and equals in Item.

Example:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

public class Catalogue {

    private Map<Integer, Item> catalogue;

    public Catalogue () { 
      catalogue = new HashMap<Integer, Item>();
    }

    public void findItem(int prodcode) {
        Item item = catalogue.get(prodcode);
        if (item != null) {
            System.out.println("Found item: " + item);
        } else {
            System.out.println("Item with code " + prodcode + " was not found.");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thankyou for the replies.
I have decided it is probably best I do not use hashmap as this seems to stop my other methods working and I do not want to have to change all my methods.

Is there a way of me searching for a matching product code using array list and iterator?

Comment: Do you think it is better for me to get used to using hashmap instead of arraylist? I will probably be working on things for my learning which will involve me creating object which need to be classified & listed by their attributes (prod code, colour etc) Perhaps I should get familiar with hashmap now instead of sticking to arraylist do you think?

Comment: If you are usually looking up your Items by code (and those codes are not simply `0..N`, where they could be used as the indexes in a ArrayList), then a Map (either HashMap or TreeMap) is more useful.

Answer (score 0):

`List` offers O(n) when search, o(1) when add. But if you make it in order and binary-search, you could get O(long n);

You could also use `TreeMap`, it offers O(log n) when search and add.

While `HashMap` always offers O(1);